# How do we do DNS query in Python

Tags: python, dns

How do we do a DNS query, expecially MX query, in Python by not installing any third party libs.

I want to query the MX record about a domain, however, it seems that `socket.getaddrinfo` can only query the A record.

I have tried this:

```
python -c "import socket; print socket.getaddrinfo('baidu.com', 25, socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)"
```

This prints

```
[(2, 2, 17, '', ('220.181.57.217', 25)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('123.125.114.144', 25)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('180.149.132.47', 25))]
```

However, we can not telnet it with `telnet 220.181.57.217 25` or `telnet 123.125.114.144 25` or `telnet 180.149.132.47 25`.

Comment: Can you show what You have tried so far. .:) ..If hadn't tried anything and then give a try looking at this particular Link http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html . I hope this helps

Comment: @csharpcode, i have updated the question. I have searched that dnspython lib. However, i think maybe python have some dns functionality inside it, even  it is poor.

Comment: No way, to my knowledge. DNS resolution is quite complex, and you need a specialised package, like dnspython. `socket.getaddrinfo` actually is a wrapper around libc `getaddrinfo`, so you are not doing DNS resolution but accessing the OS resolver stack (which may comprise DNS resolution, but not only.)

Comment: @StefanoM, If then, then thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some rough low-level code for making a dns request using just the standard library if anyone's interested.

```
import secrets
import socket

# https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035
# https://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters/dns-parameters.xhtml#table-dns-parameters-4


def dns_request(name, qtype=1, addr=('127.0.0.53', 53), timeout=1):  # A 1, NS 2, CNAME 5, SOA 6, NULL 10, PTR 12, MX 15, TXT 16, AAAA 28, NAPTR 35, * 255
    name = name.rstrip('.')
    queryid = secrets.token_bytes(2)
    # Header. 1 for Recursion Desired, 1 question, 0 answers, 0 ns, 0 additional
    request = queryid + b'\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0'
    # Question
    for label in name.rstrip('.').split('.'):
        assert len(label) < 64, name
        request += int.to_bytes(len(label), length=1, byteorder='big')
        request += label.encode()
    request += b'\0'  # terminates with the zero length octet for the null label of the root.
    request += int.to_bytes(qtype, length=2, byteorder='big')  # QTYPE
    request += b'\0\1'  # QCLASS = 1
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
        s.sendto(request, addr)
        s.settimeout(timeout)
        try:
            response, serveraddr = s.recvfrom(4096)
        except socket.timeout:
            raise TimeoutError(name, timeout)
    assert serveraddr == addr, (serveraddr, addr)
    assert response[:2] == queryid, (response[:2], queryid)
    assert response[2] & 128  # QR = Response
    assert not response[2] & 4  # No Truncation
    assert response[3] & 128  # Recursion Available
    error_code = response[3] % 16  # 0 = no error, 1 = format error, 2 = server failure, 3 = does not exist, 4 = not implemented, 5 = refused
    qdcount = int.from_bytes(response[4:6], 'big')
    ancount = int.from_bytes(response[6:8], 'big')
    assert qdcount <= 1
    # parse questions
    qa = response[12:]
    for question in range(qdcount):
        domain, qa = parse_qname(qa, response)
        qtype, qa = parse_int(qa, 2)
        qclass, qa = parse_int(qa, 2)
    # parse answers
    answers = []
    for answer in range(ancount):
        domain, qa = parse_qname(qa, response)
        qtype, qa = parse_int(qa, 2)
        qclass, qa = parse_int(qa, 2)
        ttl, qa = parse_int(qa, 4)
        rdlength, qa = parse_int(qa, 2)
        rdata, qa = qa[:rdlength], qa[rdlength:]
        if qtype == 1:  # IPv4 address
            rdata = '.'.join(str(x) for x in rdata)
        if qtype == 15:  # MX
            mx_pref, rdata = parse_int(rdata, 2)
        if qtype in (2, 5, 12, 15):  # NS, CNAME, MX
            rdata, _ = parse_qname(rdata, response)
        answer = (qtype, domain, ttl, rdata, mx_pref if qtype == 15 else None)
        answers.append(answer)
    return error_code, answers


def parse_int(byts, ln):
    return int.from_bytes(byts[:ln], 'big'), byts[ln:]


def parse_qname(byts, full_response):
    domain_parts = []
    while True:
        if byts[0] // 64:  # OFFSET pointer
            assert byts[0] // 64 == 3, byts[0]
            offset, byts = parse_int(byts, 2)
            offset = offset - (128 + 64) * 256  # clear out top 2 bits
            label, _ = parse_qname(full_response[offset:], full_response)
            domain_parts.append(label)
            break
        else:  # regular QNAME
            ln, byts = parse_int(byts, 1)
            label, byts = byts[:ln], byts[ln:]
            if not label:
                break
            domain_parts.append(label.decode())
    return '.'.join(domain_parts), byts
```

Answer (score 1):

First Install dnspython

```
import dns.resolver

answers = dns.resolver.query('dnspython.org', 'MX')
for rdata in answers:
    print 'Host', rdata.exchange, 'has preference', rdata.preference
```